# <algorithm> vector sort with objects?

Tags: c++, algorithm, class, sorting, vector

So, in the c++ documentation in the  header there is a nice function that lets you sort vectors. I have a class `Person`. I have a vector of pointers to objects of that class (`vector<Person*>`) and I want to compare the people by different parameters, for example age, length of name and so on.

I already have functions which return the needed variables but I am not sure how to do that. Here is a link to the sort vector function in the c++ reference http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/sort/

Comment: @Ripounet if you are going to suggest edits to a question please fix everything not just the typo in the title. Take a look at the revisions to see what else needed to be fixed on this post

Answer (score 14, accepted):

That's so simple:

```
struct student
{
  string name;
  string grade;
};

bool cmd(const student & s1, const student & s2)
{
   if (s1.name != s2.name) return s1.name < s2.name;
   return s1.grade < s2.grade;
}
```

Then:

```
vector<student> s;
sort(s.begin(), s.end(), cmd);
```

Students will be sorted alphabatically. If two students have the same name, they will be  ordered using their grade.

Comment: Thanks! Please consider choosing the answer as the best if you feel it resolves your problem.

Comment: I will in 3 minutes after the system timer lets me.

Answer (score -1):

Try to override operator like "<", ">" using the same properties of the objects. After that you can redefine some sort operation.