# Sort vector of objects with multiple sorting criteria

Tags: c++, sorting, object, vector, overloading

```
class Point2D
{
    friend ostream& operator<< (ostream&, const Point2D&);
    protected:
            int x;         //can sort by x
            int y;         //can sort by y
            double dist;   //can sort by dist

    public:  
            Point2D () {x=0; y=0;}              
            Point2D (int a, int b) {x=a; y=b;}      
            void setX (int);
            void setY (int);
            void setDist();
            double getDist() const;     
            int getX ();
            int getY ();

}

int main()
{
    vector<Point2D> vect;
    sort (vect.begin(), vect.end());

    //Print all vector elements
    for (int x=0; x<vect.size(); x++)
        cout <<  vect[x] << endl;      
}
```

I am trying to sort **vector of objects** using `sort`.

But when I run my codes above, I get plenty of repeating errors saying:

`instantiated from here - sort (vect.begin(), vect.end());`

I want to be able to sort by either **x, y or dist**. 
I guess I probably need to overload the `>` or `==` operators in order for me to use the `sort` provided by C++ std library?

How would the code for overloading look like? I know how to overload ostream operators like `<<` to display data, but in this complicated situation, how do we do the overloading in order to allow us to use `sort`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If your compiler supports C++11, You could do something like:

```
vector<Point2D> vect;
// sort by x
sort (vect.begin(), vect.end(), [](Point2D const &a, Point2D const &b) { return a.getX() < b.getX(); });
// sort by y
sort (vect.begin(), vect.end(), [](Point2D const &a, Point2D const &b) { return a.getY() < b.getY(); });
```

Note, for the above example to work you have either to define your member functions `getX` and `getY` as `const`s or remove the `const` qualifiers from the input arguments of the lambdas.

If your compiler doesn't support C++11 then you can define comparables like below:

```
bool compare_x(Point2D const &a, Point2D const &b)
{
  return a.getX() < b.getX();
}

bool compare_y(Point2D const &a, Point2D const &b)
{
  return a.getY() < b.getY();
}
```

and call `sort` like below:

```
  // sort by x
  sort(vect.begin(), vect.end(), compare_x);
  // sort by y
  sort(vect.begin(), vect.end(), compare_y);
```

Comment: So I don't really need to do overloading in order to use C++ stdlib's `sort` ?

Comment: No you don't need to overload.

Comment: When I run your suggested codes, I get `expected primary-expression before '[' and ']' and 'const'`.

Comment: @user3437460 wait a sec.

Comment: @40two I think it will be helpful to add a solution that doesn't depend on C++11 since the OP tagged C++, not C++11.

Comment: @user3437460 either define your `getX()` and `getY()` member functions as `const` which is recomended or remove the `const` qualifier from the input arguments of the lambdas in my answer.

Comment: @40two I tried all the things you mentioned, but sadly it only generates more errors. By the way, what is `[` and `]` used for.. my compiler keep giving error on that 2 square brackets..

Comment: @user3437460 `[](...){...}` is a lambda expression it's supported in C++11 and beyond. Please look at the update, I provide a c++0x version as well.

Comment: @user3437460 Add `-std=c++11` as a compiler option.

Comment: @40two Your codes with the comparable is extacly what I need...thank you so much..or your time and help. +25 points of rep from me.

Comment: @40two: just a note C++0x is *'pre-official'* C++11, you provided a C++11 and a C++03 version.

Comment: @40two Do you mind further improve your solution by showing comparables for sorting(x then y)? Which means sorting by 2 criteria concurrently.

Comment: @user3437460 This is not possible, you sort according to one criterion at a time.

Comment: @40two It is possible actually, I found it here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14081335/algorithm-vector-sort-with-objects Thanks anyway!